# Is it possible to play online with an XBox Live Silver account?

Tags: xbox-network, xbox-360

I do not own an XBox, but a friend of mine does. I recently changed my regular on-console gamer profile to an XBox Live Silver profile so that I can use my profile on any XBox. I do want to play online occasionally, but I have heard that it is not possible to play online with a Silver profile.

I've seen several places say that its possible to play with online for select games; is this true? Where might I find such a list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As it currently stands, [you must have Gold privileges](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/live/joinlive) - either from your account, as part of a Family Pack, or as part of a promotion - to play online. Free (formerly known as Silver) and local accounts cannot otherwise play online.

At one point, Microsoft did offer online play to Free/Silver members [for select titles](http://kotaku.com/5030272/free-xbox-live-silver-online-play-confirmed-explained-limited), but it was for a limited time, and that no longer appears to be the case.

Final Fantasy XI is an exception, though: you can play online [even with an Xbox Live Free account](http://www.playonline.com/ff11us/envi/xbox/xbox01.html).

Comment: One notable exception is Final Fantasy XI, which does not require a Gold account to play online. That game does require its own monthly subscription, though, which somewhat explains the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I've updated and linked accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware, it is only possible to play multiplayer games online through Xbox Live if you have a gold account, or if you are playing on a Free Gold Weekend, which are special, and often rare, events that happen often to celebrate the release of a new title or occasionally for holidays.

Answer (score 1):

You can play online with silver on certain games if you're on the same console and playing with a person who has gold. For example, the Halo games, although various limitations apply. There is a somewhat relevant list [here.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/48318/current-4-player-split-screen-console-games-with-either-bots-or-online-as-of-jan)

Answer (score 1):

You can play some games, as I have Crackdown 2 and I can play on multiplayer still.

Comment: Xbox Live Gold is free this weekend, have you been playing online before this?  http://www.xbox.com/en-US/community/promotions/summer-of-sports?uid=8418851&tid

Answer (score 1):

I just went on cod mw3, for some reason it's letting me play on silver. I don't have any  complaints!

Answer (score -3):

It is possible to play with friends on silver xbox live. You need to have another friend that is silver xbox live and then your two friends can play together.

Comment: This information doesn't seem correct to me. Are you referring to the "Guest" feature some games have? If so, could you be  a little more clear and specific in your answer?